# How to position images using Semantic Grid System/Less?

Tags: css, grid, semantics, less

I'm having trouble positioning images w/ Semantic Grid System.  No problem with text.

With text, the example code works fine.  HTML:

```
<body>
<article>Main</article>
<section>Sidebar</section>
</body>
```

LESS:

```
@import 'grid.less';

@columns: 12;
@column-width: 60;
@gutter-width: 20;

article {
.column(9);
}
section {
.column(3);
}
```

The same implementation with the following for an image in the HTML:

```
<body>
<article>Mainr</article>
<section><img src="title.png"
       width="705"
       height="66.5"
       alt="Title"
       class="pngimg"></section>
</body>
```

Fails to position the image.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: works for me, in which way it fails to position the image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you refer to the image being wider then your columns? This is because browsers don't scale images even if their container is to small. In your case you have a `.column(3)` which should render to a width of 220px and an image which is 705px wide.

Best way to solve your problem is to manually scale the image to a width of 220px or to set `width="100%"` in your image tag (remove the height in this case).